# SSL Error on Python GET Request

Tags: python, ssl, get, python-requests

I am trying to do a simple GET request to this url: [link](https://www.bbvafrances.com.ar/francesGo2-Portal/institucional/busqueda.do?m=&page=1)

Here's the basic python code which I already use for other urls and works.

```
url = 'http://www.bbvafrances.com.ar/francesGo2-Portal/institucional/busqueda.do?m=&page=1'
r = requests.get(url)
print r.text
```

The thing is that with this particular url I get an SSL error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "frances.py", line 134, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url,verify=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 335, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 454, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 144, in   resolve_redirects
    allow_redirects=False,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 438, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 331, in send
raise SSLError(e)
 requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1408F119:SSL     routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac
```

Any ideas on what is going on with this particular url that makes the request crash?
I tried adding custom headers but still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Now I'm trying with this SSL way suggested as an answer.

```
url = 'https://www.bbvafrances.com.ar/francesGo2-Portal/institucional/busqueda.do?m=&page=1'
s = requests.Session()
s.mount(url, SSLAdapter(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3))
r = s.get(url)
print r.text
```

This is the new trace: (almost identical to the first one)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "frances.py", line 138, in <module>
    r = s.get(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 463, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 451, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 557, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 420, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1408F119:SSL         routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac
```

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce your problem, and can confirm this doesn't happen on other HTTPS sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the server announces support for TLS1.0 but if you actually try to talk to it using TLS1.0 it will break. Instead you have to use SSL3.

You can do so by using the `SSLAdapter` included with the `requests_toolbelt` package:
http://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user.html#ssladapter.

Then use `ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3` instead of the one shown in the documentation.

Comment: Very cool answer about the requests_toolbelt package, but sadly I am still getting the same error: requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac

Comment: BTW the correct way of calling the parameter was ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3

Comment: I corrected the type. Are you sure you made the request with the session containing the new adapter? And did you mount the adapter for all of `https://`?

Comment: Check out the edit...that is my whole code. Only one request and that's the one that breaks.