# SSL Error On Python Request

Tags: python, ssl, request

I'm trying to make a request to an API using Python, but I'm getting an **SSL error**. I've searched it everywhere, but can't seem to find a fix.

This is the versions I have installed on my virtual environment:

```
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 26 2016, 12:10:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015'
```

I'm trying to use the code I found on [this blog](https://lukasa.co.uk/2013/01/Choosing_SSL_Version_In_Requests/):

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
import ssl
import requests

class SSLAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    '''An HTTPS Transport Adapter that uses an arbitrary SSL version.'''
    def __init__(self, ssl_version=None, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_version = ssl_version

        super(SSLAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=self.ssl_version)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://msesandbox.cisco.com:8081/api/location/v2/clients?sortBy=lastLocatedTime:DESC'
    s = requests.Session()
    s.mount("https://", SSLAdapter(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv2))
    response = s.get(url) #line that trigger the mistake.
    print (response)
```

This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file", line 23, in <module>
    response = s.get(url)
  File "/Users/rafacarv/Environments/python2_7_12_cmx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 487, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rafacarv/Environments/python2_7_12_cmx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/rafacarv/Environments/python2_7_12_cmx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rafacarv/Environments/python2_7_12_cmx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 477, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)
```

I also tried to use the suggestion I found on this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896562/ssl-error-on-python-get-request), which consists of using the **requests_toolbelt** package, but had no luck.

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> msesandbox.cisco.com:8081

This server supports only TLS 1.2, i.e. no TLS 1.0 or worse.

> 'OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015'

This OpenSSL version does not support TLS 1.2 yet. You need at least OpenSSL 1.0.1 for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I update it on my virtual environment? I'm Using a Mac to code, I'll later on deploy it on Heroku.

Comment: @rlc: You need to recompile everything. See [Updating openssl in python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752409/updating-openssl-in-python-2-7)