# SSL Error on python3 get request

Tags: python, ssl

I'm trying to access a table on factfinder.census.gov via their [API](https://factfinder.census.gov/service/getStatisticalData.html).

I've tried the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896562/ssl-error-on-python-get-request) and tried using http, all sorts of variants of this code, etc. In fact, I can't even seem to do a simple get (I'm using python requests) on http://factfinder.census.gov/ at all.

E.g.,

https://factfinder.census.gov/service/data/v1/en/programs/DEC/datasets/10_SF1/tables/GCTPH1/data/0100000US.04000

I had to tack on a user access key (from https://factfinder.census.gov/service/UserAccessKey.html) to get access, and then I could just paste https://factfinder.census.gov/service/data/v1/en/programs/DEC/datasets/10_SF1/tables/GCTPH1/data/0100000US.04000?key=MYKEY and it worked fine in private/incognito mode by just pasting it into my browser url bar)

However, I'm getting

**Error**

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='factfinder.census.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /service/data/v1/en/programs/DEC/datasets/10_SF1/tables/GCTPH1/data/0100000US.04000?key=MYKEY (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:598)'),))

Answer (score 0):

I'd hazard a guess that you're querying the link you posted (http://factfinder.census.gov/) using **http** not **https** (notice if you click that link it redirects to https), the site uses SSL encryption and is rejecting the unencrypted connection attempt.